# Modify white background of CTAN lion EPS

Tags: beamer, graphics, eps, transparency, ctan

I want to use vector image [ctanlion.eps](https://www.ctan.org/lion/files) in my beamer presentations.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default]
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=gray}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{ctanlion}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But the EPS file is not total transparent: you could still see some white areas. What is the good way to modify the EPS file, removing these white areas?

[image]

Comment: whoever painted it didn't fill all. Put it over a gray (tikz) box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would open it up in `inkscape`, put a coloured rectangular box behind it so I can see what is going on, ungroup the lion, then delete the white objects. Once you're happy that all the white is removed, delete your coloured rectangle, and save it back out as either a PDF or EPS. (I've just done this if you can think of a way for me to get it to you.)

Comment: Thank You. Could you send a copy to me? You may see my email address in my profile page.

Comment: Just emailed it though.

Comment: Got it. And maybe you could also send it to CTAN mantainers, to benefit more people.

Comment: Good idea. I'll clean them up and put offer them in a range of formats to CTAN.